# Running single maven testng file in jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins

Im a beginner. Needing to know how to run a Maven single testng file in Jenkins.

I tried using

```
<suiteXmlFiles>
<suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
</suiteXmlFiles>
```

It works fine in Maven but not in Jenkins. Jenkins shows following error,

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ FrontOffice ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 4 source files to E:\Security Testing\Luna Workspace\FrontOffice\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /E:/Security Testing/Luna Workspace/FrontOffice/src/main/java/BaseClass/RetryAnalyzer.java:[3,18] package org.testng does not exist
[ERROR] /E:/Security Testing/Luna Workspace/FrontOffice/src/main/java/BaseClass/RetryAnalyzer.java:[4,18] package org.testng does not exist
[ERROR] /E:/Security Testing/Luna Workspace/FrontOffice/src/main/java/BaseClass/RetryAnalyzer.java:[6,39] cannot find symbol
  symbol: class IRetryAnalyzer
[ERROR] /E:/Security Testing/Luna Workspace/FrontOffice/src/main/java/BaseClass/RetryAnalyzer.java:[10,32] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ITestResult
```

My POM File :

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Could you be more specific about "It works fine in Maven but not in Jenkins"? Because Jenkins would just invoke Maven commands as you do in local environment.

Comment: did you verify that the setting.xml on your machine  and on Jenkins slave are identical ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, You've create surefire plugin, now You have to create an maven job, and in Build section under goals add

```
clean test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=/path/to/testng.xml
```

but to be sure it would work, try it first in command line:

```
mvn clean test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=/path/to/testng.xml
```

in Jenkins remove "mvn" keywords, its not needed.

Hope it helps,

Answer (score 0):

Add Test NG to your build dependencies.